# How to check in real time if data was enteder from one of the classes into a texbox?

Tags: c#, verification, savefiledialog

My question comes from a problem which I have right now. I have MainWindow, AuthenticateWindow, and AddEntryWindow which all are WinForms. In main window I have possibility to Authenticate and Add Entry into my main windows textbox. They can not add an entry until they authenticate (no problem with this). I need to add an entry to the text box which will update my main windows textbox. The problem if, how can I check if entry was added to my textbox?

I am trying to have a Save option from menu strip. I am getting an error whenever I am trying to save an empty file. How could I authenticate the saving process by Save button by having it first disabled, and enabled after entry was added?

I could always verify if if textbox had an entry but I want to have button disabled first, and enabled after entry was added. I do not have a privilege to do so as of right now.

Please ask questions if I am not clear enough.

```
private void tsmiSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Open sfdSaveToLocation which let us choose the
    // location where we want to save the file.
    if (txtDisplay.Text != string.Empty)
    {
        sfdSaveToLocation.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.cs**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Store_Passwords_and_Serial_Codes
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Form
    {
        private AuthenticateUser storedAuth;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MainWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Prohibit editing.
            txtDisplay.Enabled = false;
        }

        public string ChangeTextBox
        {
            get
            {
                return this.txtDisplay.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                this.txtDisplay.Text = value;
            }
        }

        private void tsmiAuthenticate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AuthenticationWindow authWindow = new AuthenticationWindow();
            authWindow.ShowDialog();
            storedAuth = authWindow.Result;
        }

        private void tsmiAddEntry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (storedAuth == null)
            {
                DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show
                    ("You must log in before you add an entry." 
                    + Environment.NewLine + "You want to authenticate?",
                    "Information", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, 
                    MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    AuthenticationWindow authWindow = 
                        new AuthenticationWindow();
                    authWindow.ShowDialog();
                    storedAuth = authWindow.Result;

                    AddEntryWindow addWindow = new AddEntryWindow
                        (this, storedAuth.UserName, storedAuth.Password);
                    addWindow.ShowDialog();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                AddEntryWindow addWindow = new AddEntryWindow
                    (this, storedAuth.UserName, storedAuth.Password);
                addWindow.ShowDialog();
            }
        }

        private void tsmiClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void tsmiSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Open sfdSaveToLocation which let us choose the
            // location where we want to save the file.
            sfdSaveToLocation.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void sfdSaveToLocation_FileOk(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            string theFileName = sfdSaveToLocation.FileName;

            EncryptDecrypt en = new EncryptDecrypt();

            string encrypted = en.Encrypt(txtDisplay.Text,
                storedAuth.UserName, storedAuth.Password);

            MessageBox.Show(encrypted);

            File.WriteAllText(theFileName, encrypted);
        }
    }
}
```

**AddEntryWindow.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
// Needed to be used with StringBuilder
using System.Text;
// Needed to be used with ArrayList.
using System.Collections;

namespace Store_Passwords_and_Serial_Codes
{
    public partial class AddEntryWindow : Form
    {
        string user, pass;

        // Initializind ArrayList to store all data needed to be added or retrived.
        private ArrayList addedEntry = new ArrayList();

        // Initializing MainWindow form.
        MainWindow mainWindow;

        // Default constructor to initialize the form.
        public AddEntryWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public AddEntryWindow(MainWindow viaParameter, string user, string pass)
            : this()
        {
            mainWindow = viaParameter;
            this.user = user;
            this.pass = pass;
        }

        private void AddEntryWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { }

        private void btnAddEntry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Making sure that type is selected.
            if (cmbType.SelectedIndex == -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select entry type!", "Error!", 
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            // Each field must be filled for specified type.
            // Here we are checking if all fields were filled.
            else if ((cmbType.SelectedIndex == 0 && (txtUserName.Text == string.Empty || txtPassword.Text == string.Empty)) ||
                (cmbType.SelectedIndex == 1 && (txtURL.Text == string.Empty || txtPassword.Text == string.Empty)) ||
                (cmbType.SelectedIndex == 2 && (txtSoftwareName.Text == string.Empty || txtSerialCode.Text == string.Empty)))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please fill all the fields!", "Error!", 
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                int totalEntries = 0;

                if(cmbType.SelectedIndex == 0)
                    addedEntry.Add(new AddPC(cmbType.Text, 
                        txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text));

                else if(cmbType.SelectedIndex == 1)
                    addedEntry.Add(new AddWebSite(cmbType.Text, 
                        txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text, txtURL.Text));

                else if(cmbType.SelectedIndex == 2)
                    addedEntry.Add(new AddSerialCode(cmbType.Text, 
                        txtSoftwareName.Text, txtSerialCode.Text));

                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                foreach (var list in addedEntry)
                {
                    if (list is AddPC)
                    {
                        totalEntries++;
                        AddPC tmp = (AddPC)list;
                        stringBuilder.Append(tmp.ToString());
                    }
                    else if (list is AddWebSite)
                    {
                        totalEntries++;
                        AddWebSite tmp = (AddWebSite)list;
                        stringBuilder.Append(tmp.ToString());
                    }
                    else if (list is AddSerialCode)
                    {
                        totalEntries++;
                        AddSerialCode tmp = (AddSerialCode)list;
                        stringBuilder.Append(tmp.ToString());
                    }
                }

                mainWindow.ChangeTextBox = stringBuilder.ToString();

                mainWindow.tsslStatus.Text = "A total of " + totalEntries + " entries added.";

                // Clearing all fields.
                ClearFields();
            }
        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClearFields();
        }

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Closing the Add Entry Window form.
            this.Close();
        }

        private void cmbType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Deciding which data must be entered depending on
            // what type is selected from combo box.

            // PC
            if (cmbType.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {}
            // Web Site
            else if (cmbType.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {}
            // Serial Code
            else if (cmbType.SelectedIndex == 2)
            {}
        }

        private void ClearFields()
        {
            // Clearing all fields to the default state.
        }
    }
}
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you *probably* just want to subscribe to the [`TextChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx) event, which will be fired whenever the text in the textbox changes.

I can't say I really followed everything that you're doing, but I think you *should* be fine to just enable or disable your Save button within that event handler.

EDIT: It's not really clear where all your different components live, but you want something like:

```
// Put this after the InitializeComponent() call in the constructor.
txtDisplay.TextChanged += HandleTextBoxTextChanged;

...

private void HandleTextBoxTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool gotText = txtDisplay.Text.Length > 0;
    menuSaveButton.Enabled = gotText;
}
```

I'd also *strongly* advise you not to use `ArrayList` but to use the generic `List<T>` type. The non-generic collections should almost never be used in new code.

Comment: Well, I could do set the button at public. Is that the easiest option?

Comment: @HelpNeeder: It's not really clear what you mean, but you shouldn't make any fields public. Do you understand how to add an event handler?

Comment: I don't know much about event handler. I had one lab about it which I got 100% but it's simple to use code but not understand it. Please explain.

Comment: @HelpNeeder: If you're using the Windows Forms designer, you should be able to click on the text box, then click on the lightning icon in the Properties window, find the TextChanged handler, and type the name of a method to handle the event. Visual Studio will create that method, and you can make that method enable or disable the Save button. Alternatively you could do all of this in code directly if you wanted.

Comment: I like the code :) Please explain. +1 for hints. I will try it right now.

Comment: Oh, well AddEntry button it already have to do something. I can only choose 1 method at the time. So I need to do this prosaically. As my guess.

Comment: @HelpNeeder: Your last comment wasn't at all clear, but I can't see anything to suggest that you already have a handler for the textbox's TextChanged event. I'll add the code you'd need, but you'd probably be better off using the designer.

Comment: What isn't clear to you? Please tell. I do know I am not the English Ph.D, nor close (my english language logic sucks lol). I am just trying to avoid having public/internal variables.

Comment: @HelpNeeder: This sentence doesn't make sense: "Oh, well AddEntry button it already have to do something." It feels like you're really trying to bite off a bit much in one go - I would actually start learning C# with console applications; GUIs are tricky to get right even when you know the language well, let alone when you're trying to understand that at the same time.

Comment: You are surprisingly right :D my class teaches me so much about c#. The problem is that hey don't define problems that might occur with it. Basics in c# class are sometimes useless.

Comment: When my professor said "after this class you should know of how to build creative and well created applications." I did laugh. hahahaha